# Ubuntu Software-center: no permission to install software

Tags: permissions, software-center, 17.10

I've just installed a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop. I've barely made any changes. Just trying to configure XRDP now according to [this](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=11184) description.

Now I'm trying to install an app (Gnome Tweak) from the Ubuntu Software-center. However, this fails.
"Unable to install "[app]": you do not have permission to install software.

[image]

I've looked for a solution and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333919/no-permissions-for-software-center). However, my there's nothing wrong with my org.debian.apt.policy file.

Using sudo in a terminal doesn't give an error.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
Try running the store as:  `sudo gnome-software`
This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem in Ubuntu 17.10 . Checked org.debian.apt.policy and all permissions are auth_admin or auth_admin_keep. Synaptic and Aptitude work fine if I start them as root.

My real problem, however, was that I was trying to install software from 'software-center', which after some research I discovered is now called gnome-software, I would get the same error that you listed. After finding [this policykit addition](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1340973), which didn't work in my case even after I updated the filename to match the new software-center, I found the problem.

This is apparently a [little known bug with XFCE in Ubuntu](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=841878) where it tries to use policykit-1 instead of policykit-1-gnome. Even running 'pkexec synaptic' on the command line would fail (just as described in the bug). Installing policykit-1-gnome fixed this issue for me.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Are you running Wayland or Xorg?

Comment: Sorry, did not work for me... installing `policykit-1-gnome`. Do I need to do something extra?