# Don't have permission to install software (Ubuntu 17:10) via Ubuntu Software-center

Tags: permissions, software-center

My Ubuntu Software-Center doesn't allow me to install any software (even though logged in with admin account). I looked into the following topic, but doesn't seem to help in my case: [Ubuntu Software-center: no permission to install software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970838/ubuntu-software-center-no-permission-to-install-software)

Any suggestions? I'm not very hardcore in Ubuntu yet, thus step-by-step required :)

Thanks!

Rob

Comment: Are you trying to install a snap? You must log in with Ubuntu One account to install snaps. This should be obvious from the dialog appearing to log you in, though.

Comment: Nope, just through the regular software center.

Comment: Ah, are you using Xubuntu (or xfce installed on Ubuntu)?